# IOS UIWebView with pages that refresh issue

Tags: html, uiwebview, refresh, ios-4.2

I am using a UIWebView to show a couple websites within my app.

I have noticed that even when the view is not active / visible
(say when I move to another tab), it still
updates HTML refresh messages.

stopLoading does nothing as the pages are already loaded .

How do I get the UIWebView to "ignore" ongoing HTML refresh messages?

I assume some kind of call in webViewDidFinishLoading.

Answer (score 0):

If your delegate is receiving the [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) message, you can simply return NO to prevent the reload. Or you may be able to inject javascript to disable the reload using [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIWebView). Otherwise, you're out of luck.

Comment: how are others trapping these refreshes, I know it has to be going on in a bunch of apps, but maybe devs have just let these refreshes happen in the past. My issue is I have a couple of these views and they start to cause issues with streaming video / audio over cellular.